# why I can't decode the ‘utf8’ string in python2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, standards, decode

I use python write:

```
'\xF5\x90\x90\x90'.decode('utf8')
```

But it make error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The string`\xF5\x90\x90\x90` is a standard 'utf8' string.
It's binary is `11110101 10010000 10010000 10010000`.
Comply with the rules of utf8 ：11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx

why I can't decode this string ?

Comment: What you have is a unicode string, which you can **encode**, not decode. Also, in Python 2, you need to prefix it with a **u**: u`'\xF5\x90\x90\x90'.encode('utf8')`

Comment: @HaiVu No, I don't think so. For example, `u'\xE2\x99\xA1'` and `'\xE2\x99\xA1'.decode('utf8')` are totally different things, and obviously the OP wants the 2nd one. @MarkRansom's answer shall be the true reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description):

> In November 2003, UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to end at U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding.

The character you're trying to decode is outside of this range. Specifically it's U+150410.

Comment: So UTF-8 can't represent all characters anymore?

Comment: @MartinKonecny it depends on what you mean by "all characters". Unicode itself only goes up to U+10FFFF, anything beyond that is undefined. If you mean "all binary permutations" then no, it can't represent them all.

Comment: I see, so UTF-8 was restricted to match Unicode restriction. Thanks